# How to deal with page breaks when printing detail list with ul tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a project which requires printing an HTML list with many detail items.

My problem is the way the list is printed over multiple page. It will sometimes cut a list item in half. I wanna notify page break when printing finished.

I wanna do this by css.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please review [ask] a question and post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to avoid page breaks inside your UL.

```
@media print {
    ul {page-break-inside: avoid;}
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.asp